# Form method GET not working with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I have read multiple answers on this forum, but none seem to work for me or they just didn't explain their answer..

I have a form that uses GET as a method. Since I am using mod_rewrite the form doesn't work anymore. I have read something about using %{QUERYSTRING} in your .htacces but I couldn't find any good information on how to do it. The GET method works if i change the "?" to a "&". For me this is logic because I already use a question mark in my .htacces.

Can someone please explain to me how to use a form with a GET method in combination with mod_rewrite?

Thanks!

My .htacces looks like this at the moment:

```
    Options -Indexes 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    index.php?page=%1&id=%2&code=%3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE:**

The URL that i used was: 
rechtenkrom.nl/zoek-opdracht?id=&trefwoord=&headId=&categorie=&postcode=&distance=&provincie=&submit=

When I did a var_dump($_GET) it didn't show me any GET variables after the "?".
By adding QSA to my last rewrite rule it now sees all the GET variables :)

Comment: You should expound a bit on the other answers you're referring to. If answers on other questions seem useful, you should provide links to them and explain exactly what it is about those answers that is insufficient for you. Also, you have the rep to comment everywhere (awarded at 50), so you can leave comments on those other answers asking for clarification.

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Comment: What URL are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that with your last RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule .*    index.php?page=%1&id=%2&code=%3 [QSA,L]
```

QSA = When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted! I will update my answer with the link that I tried to use. Thank you very much.